# Could the following basic tensorflow model learn? Is this the right approach?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I started playing with tensor flow as this:

My training data consists of a array like this (for this example, the len is 3, but for my real example the len is 100):

```
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]

....
then it repeats itself until a 1000
... 

[1, 0 , 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```

My labels data consists of a list of array which display he number 1 position:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 .....] until 1000.
```

I am using the following configuration for the model, but the accuracy seems pretty low. So i guess it's not event close to learning. Did I interpreted wrongly how tensor flow works? Could anybody give me a hint about how this problem be solved?

```
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=50, batch_size=100)
```

Comment: If you want "a number" as a result, you need `Dense(1)` at the end. `Dense(100, activation='softmax')` is for "classification problems with 100 classes". Your problem itself doesn't make much sense, as your inputs are what you would expect as outputs of a classification model. But if you want a regression problem, then a `Dense(1)` at the end would serve, but there isn't such a thing as "accuracy" for continuous numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I am still new to this IA, but it seems that using categorical cross entropy was able to achieve what I wanted in this demo example. For some reason I could pass an array with as training data ie [0,0,1] and pass a training label of 3 .... and the acurracy is 1 (which was what i was expecting). If i change the label to 2 , the accuracy is 0. So it classified correctly? I havent tested how to predict, but i hope I could get a number as a prediction. Thanks again. I remember i tried the dense(1) but i was receiving an error which stated "your number has to be between 0 and 1) Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about why I get that error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number of neurons in the last Dense layer should be the number of classes you want to predict. If in your case there are 3 classes, the last layer should be `Dense(3)` instead of `Dense(100)`.

Also, you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy` when your label is integer, like in your case. You use `categorical_crossentropy` when you have one-hot-encoded vector for your output. To convert to one-hot-encoded vector, you can use `to_categorical` function from keras.utils.

Refer to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for detailed explanation. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: you're welcome. can you please mark the answer as useful answer? thanks!

Comment: I did, but when you haven't reach a reputation of 15, which is my case, the upvote is not reflected in the answer. Thanks.